# Android Studio isn't opening

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-studio, jvm

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5lLlI.png)   Android isnt launching , i have tried everything almost reinstalling, changing the .vmoptions file -Xms512m

> -Xmx2048m
>
> -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=512m
>
> -XX:+UseG1GC
>
> -XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50
>
> -XX:CICompilerCount=2
>
> -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
>
> -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow
>
> -XX:+IgnoreUnrecognizedVMOptions
>
> -XX:CompileCommand=exclude,com/intellij/openapi/vfs/impl/FilePartNodeRoot,trieDescend
>
> -ea
>
> -Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false
>
> -Dsun.java2d.metal=true
>
> -Djbr.catch.SIGABRT=true
>
> -Djdk.http.auth.tunneling.disabledSchemes=""
>
> -Djdk.attach.allowAttachSelf=true
>
> -Djdk.module.illegalAccess.silent=true
>
> -Dkotlinx.coroutines.debug=off
>
> 1. **Check Task Manager**:
>
>    - Open the **Task Manager** (you can do this by right-clicking on the taskbar and selecting “Task Manager”).
>    - Look for any running instances of **Android Studio**. If you find one, end the task.
>    - Try launching **Android Studio** again.
> 2. **Verify JDK Installation**:
>
>    - Ensure that you have a **Java Development Kit (JDK)** installed. Android Studio relies on the JDK.
>    - Set up an environment variable called **`JDK_HOME`** pointing to your JDK’s root directory (e.g., **`c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21\`**).
> 3. **Check Android SDK**:
>
>    - Make sure your **Android SDK** is up to date. You can do this by navigating to **Tools > SDK Manager**.
> 4. **Run Android Studio from Command Line**:
>
>    - Open a command window by typing **`cmd`** in the Start menu search box.
>    - Change the directory to the Android Studio installation folder:
>
>      ```
>      cd "c:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-studio\bin"
>      ```
>
>      .
> 5. **Review VM Options**:
>
>    - If you’ve modified any **VM options** previously, consider reverting them to default.
>    - Edit your **JVM options** and remove any obsolete or unsupported options.
> 6. **Reinstall Android Studio**:
>
>    - If none of the above steps work, try uninstalling and then reinstalling **Android Studio**. I have tried everything still not
>      launching

Answer (score 0):

When you uninstall Android Studio some cache files and other files may remain in your user home.

For completely deleting everything of Android Studio I would perform these steps:

- Uninstall all Java versions on your system
- Delete the ENV variable JAVA_HOME
- Uninstall Android Studio
- Delete the folders `%APPDATA%\Google\AndroidStudio*`
- Delete the folders `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\AndroidStudio*`

Finally reinstall Android Studio.